# Combining Apache Jena with OpenLink Virtuoso in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jena, virtuoso

I'm using SpringBoot to develop an application combining Apache Jena with an OpenLink Virtuoso Service  instance. Checking this guide [OpenLink Documentation](https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfnativestorageprovidersjena/), I'm moving as follows:

1. Set the pom (SpringBoot is version 2.7):

```html
 <dependency>
  <!-- http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/virtuoso/jdbc/virtjdbc4.jar -->   
    <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
    <artifactId>virtjdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
          <!--http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/virtuoso/rdfproviders/jena/30/virt_jena3.jar-->   
  <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
  <artifactId>virt_jena3</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
 </dependency>
     
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
   <type>pom</type>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

2. Set the application.properties

   `virtuoso.url=jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111 virtuoso.username=dba virtuoso.password=dba`
3. Create a bean:

   ```
   public class VirtuosoTransactMain
   {    
   @Bean(name = "mainVirtuosoGraphManager")
   @Primary
   public VirtGraph getVirtualGraph(@Value("${virtuoso.url}") String url, 
                                    @Value("${virtuoso.username}") String username, 
                                    @Value("${virtuoso.password}") String password)
   {
     VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph(url,username,password);
     return set;
   }
   }
   ```
4. Test

   ```
    @SpyBean
    @Qualifier("mainVirtuosoGraphManager")  
    public VirtGraph getVirtualGraph; 
    @Test
    public void testConnection()
     {      
       Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?graph { ?s ?p ?o } } limit 100");
       VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, getVirtualGraph);
    ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
    assertTrue(results.getRowNumber()>0);
     }
   ```

The test fails because the result set seems empty. No logs or exceptions are thrown.

**Addendum:**
Port 111 is ok.

```
  ComputerName     : localhost
  RemoteAddress    : 127.0.0.1
  RemotePort       : 1111
  InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  SourceAddress    : 127.0.0.1
  TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

**Edit:**
The query is correctly performed, but I have always 0 as number of result rows.

**Edit:** The problem is my personal understanding of method "getRowNumber".

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, the problem derives from my misundertanding of the method "getRowNumber" (which gives the current row number of the result set during iteration).

Comment: It appears that you should accept this answer to yourself?